# Há como utilizar uma tabela MySQL no desenvolvimento de um app com o ionic e cordova?

Tags: php, mysql

Gostaria de saber se há como, pois estou à desenvolver um projeto simples que utiliza apenas um banco de dados.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Sim

---

Tudo vai depender to tamanho da sua aplicação, se for uma aplicação para cadastro de anotações, teria no banco uma tabela `anotacoes`, e campos como: `id`, `data`, `anotacao`, `status`, etc.

Caso seja uma aplicação com mais de uma tela, e mais informações de domínio diferente, ao acredito que seja interessante fazer mais tabelas.